# MDX Query - Calculated Member

Tags: mdx

I want to create a calculated member according to this logic:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[NewMeasures] AS ...
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    CrossJoin
    (
      {[DimensionA].[LevelA].MEMBERS}
     ,{[Measures].[NewMeasures]}
    ) ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    NonEmptyCrossJoin
    (
      {[DimensionB].[LevelB].MEMBERS}
     ,{[DimensionC].[LevelC].MEMBERS}
    ) ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube];
```

my new measure must be the division between a measure that already have ([Measures]. [MyMeasure]) and the sum of "MyMeasure" on members of the level B and C.
Ex. MyMeasure = 4 - Sum of MyMeasure for the members of Level B = 20 - Sum of MyMeasure for the members of Level C = 30
New Measure = 4/(20+30)

Sorry if it is not very clear, but did not know how else to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Uhmm something like this?(i did not check for zeros or nulls but you should)

```
WITH 
MEMBER 
[Measures].[NewMeasures] 
AS 
    [Measures].[MyMeasure] /
    SUM(
        Crossjoin(
            [DimensionB].[LevelB].MEMBERS,
            [DimensionC].[LevelC].MEMBERS
        )
        ,[Measures].[MyMeasure])
    )
```

Comment: I had already tried this, but it gives me this error:
Mondrian Error:No function matches signature '(<Set>, <Set>)'

Comment: Try it with Crossjoin.